# Fraps like programs for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any programs for Ubuntu that records the screen like **Fraps** specifically for games?

Comment: Another option, on top of recordmydesktop, is SimpleScreenRecorder, which can be installed by adding the PPA with this command: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder`, refreshing the repositories with `sudo apt-get update`, and then installing with `sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder`. If you're using a 64-bit computer, you will need to install the 32-bit libraries with `sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an app on APT called recordmydesktop (gtk-recordmydesktop with a graphical interface). Its very easy to use. You may also check this location and see what you prefer:

http://www.sysadminwiki.net/site/doku.php/os/linux/ubuntu/screen_captures_desktop_recording

You could try to use VLC movie player which is available on apt but it may be outdated so get it from here:

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

It is possible to configure it so it will record your desktop/game or whatever you need.

Comment: Instructions for doing this in VLC can be found [here](http://2buntu.com/2011/10/01/how-to-record-your-desktop-with-vlc/).

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that no-one has mentioned [a program called glc](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/wiki), which is known as the Linux equivalent of Fraps. It hasn't had much development over the last two years and can be tricky to setup, so it's worth reading the [useful wiki](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/wiki) carefully. There is an excellent tutorial [at this site](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/glc.html) which details its operation, and many videos on Youtube can be found by people who have recorded game footage with it.

However, it isn't available in the repositories, but there is a ppa here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:arand/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install glc
```

**However**, I always prefer compiling. So install the dependencies first with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libx11-dev libxxf86vm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libasound2-dev libpng12-dev
```

You then need to run these commands from 
[the wiki](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/wiki/Install):

```
wget https://github.com/nullkey/glc/raw/master/scripts/glc-build.sh
chmod a+x glc-build.sh
./glc-build.sh
```

At some stage in the process it will prompt you for your password to install. It is best not to install in anything other than the default.

Take note if it mentions anything about setting custom pointers to load libraries; this is particularly important on 64 bit systems-see the wiki for details.

Although the [full options are detailed here](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/wiki/Capture), you can capture game footage by simply running

```
glc-capture game
```

and then pressing shift F8 to begin recording to file, and press the same combination to stop. The file will be stored in your home folder.

You can either play it with

```
glc-play ~/location/of/file.glc
```

or encode it; please see [here for options](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/wiki/Encode).

It certainly isn't as easy as `recordmydesktop` and is not the quick option, but is worth learning the options and playing about with it as it is a good recorder of game action.