# Screen Recorders for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, screencast

I am looking for a screen recorder for Ubuntu 12.04,any recorder besides:

- Ezvid
- Kazam Screencaster
- RecordMyDesktop
- Ice Cream Screen Recorder
- SimpleScreenRecorder
- vokoscreen
- Webcam Studio
- XSplit Gamecaster
- ffmpeg

About ffmpeg,I'm not really sure how to install it. I am going to be recording Minecraft, so it should be capable of recording fluently without high resource usage.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions here: http://askubuntu.com/q/182944/367990 ?

Comment: I don't know how to install it I mean I did but can't find it I'm still really new in Ubuntu so, don't know how to install it :( do you know other recorders?

Answer (score 0):

Use [KAZAM SCREENCASTER](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/kazam-screencaster-gets-webcam-and.html)

Kazam is a GStreamer-based screen recording and screenshot tool for Linux. The application supports recording the entire screen (with multi-monitor support), a window or an area and features:

- customizable framerate;
- option to show/hide the mouse when recording;
- record sound from speakers and/or microphone;
- keyboard shortcuts;
- configurable delay before capturing;
- automatic file saving;
- supports mp4 (H264), webm (VP8) and avi (RAW, HUFFYUV and lossless JPEG) video formats.

To Install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/stable-series
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Comment: I already have it somehow it doesnt works on my computer because i got it free from school so it cant do a lot of stuff thanks anyways :)

Comment: im sorry, i mean,it works, but what can i use to edit the video? and what can i use to watch it?

Answer (score 0):

Although its main use is for broadcasting OBS is still a very solid screen recorder (It is based on ffmpeg).

First install ffmpeg with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

And OBS with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

It basically acts as a front-end to ffmpeg but has some quite advanced features that lets you organised video and audio inputs and such.

Source: https://obsproject.com/download#linux

Comment: I have OBS but somehow it says something like: OBS does not run on this oprating system

Comment: Does OBS works on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: When I used the first 2 commands that you put, it says:E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.