# How to Record Screen and internal Audio?

Tags: sound, screen, audio-recording, desktop-recording

Is there a way to record my screen, as well as the internal audio? Like, if I were recording a game, it would record the screen, and the sounds from the game.

Comment: For games specifically, you could try `glc`: see my answer [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100053/fraps-like-programs-for-ubuntu/192976#192976).

Answer (score 58):

[**SimpleScreenRecorder**](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) ([source code](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr)) did the trick for me when recording online playing videos. It has an (experimental) OpenGL feature. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install simplescreenrecorder
```

With the OpenGL feature you can select to record a specific application window. So you can even keep working while recording in the background. Don't play any music though, because the audios will mix together (unless, of course, you are a DJ ;) )

Comment: Works exceptionally well! Nice internal audio recording, awesome that encoding speed can be changed to get fluent higher framerate!

Comment: I can not recommend this enough. It works and it is intuitive – give it a shot!

Comment: As of 17.04 it is in the official repositories and you don't need to add the PPA.

Comment: does it record the voice/audio you speak into the microphone?

Comment: @MycrofD yes it does - make sure you are using the correct audio input source (built-in worked for me).

Comment: 2021 update: you don't need the extra PPA, `simplescreenrecorder` is now included in the standard repositories (universe).

Comment: simplescreenrecorder worked for me too. Under Audio set Backend to PulseAudio, and set Source to whatever device your sound comes out of.

You can control whether or not it also records external audio (from the computer's microphone): while simplescreenrecorder is recording, open pavucontrol (the GUI for PulseAudio volume control). In the Recording tab, to get internal audio only, select 'Monitor of Built-in Analog Stereo'. Or if you want both internal and external audio select 'Built-in Analog Stereo'.

I'd ignore OpenGL unless you know you need it, it seems to be a more advanced option.

Comment: Did not work with me. Error '[PageRecord::StartOutput] Error: An error occurred during initialization.' I tried changing the video/audio settings but nothing. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I'm using this bad boy every day now to record my work and you can start with the last settings used in hidden-mode: `simplescreenrecorder --start-recording --start-hidden`. << Time saver right there

Comment: Be carefull, after installing and starting this my Remotedekstop connection was no longer working...

Comment: @Boern were you recording on the remote computer? If that is the case a workaround could be to record on your computer while remoting in full screen.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe [RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) could work for you? It has the ability to record your screen and audio, but I'm not sure if it supports games.

You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
```

If you want a GUI, you need to also install one of the packages `gtk-recordmydesktop` (GTK) or `recorditnow` (Qt)

It is discontinued but it does work as expected.

Comment: It's quite hard to use it with Games unfortunately, I found the OpenGL recorder quite bad last time I tried it

Comment: This worked otherwise, but I did not get internal audio straight or not with Jack.

The UI is quite unintuitive also – the first time I had five recordings going on before I realised the big squares on the panel are meant to represent stop symbols! And I am a graphic designer in addition to being a programmer...

Comment: It's using microphone, not the internal audio.

Comment: Does the `recordmydesktop` process store data into a disk while recording, or holds everything in RAM and flashes the data only when you signal to terminate the process?

Comment: @mercury0114: It records to disk. Once you terminate the process, it appears to do some conversion to a more appropriate compressed format.

Answer (score 4):

`1`. Install OBS as in: https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#linux

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

`2`. Open OBS; in the Mixer panel, click the "gear" of "Desktop Audio", then "Properties" and Select "Built-In Audio Analog Stereo"

`3`. Again in the Mixer panel, silence the microphone/Aux clicking on
its volume icon

`4a`. Video_Source_Method_1. In the "Sources" panel, click the <kbd>+</kbd> and Select <kbd>Screen Capture XSHM</kbd>. Saves mouse pointer if box checked.

`4b`. Video_Source_Method_2. Install VLC: (doesn't save mouse)

- `sudo snap install vlc` [source](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)
- Install plugin: `sudo apt install vlc-plugin-access-extra` [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023896/unable-to-capture-screen-with-vlc-on-ubuntukde-17-10)
- In VLC: "Capture Device": "Desktop", configure "MRL" `screen://`. You should see your screen inside VLC
- In OBS, in "Sources" panel, add <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>VLC video source</kbd>, configure ⚙; in "playlist"; <kbd>+</kbd>; <kbd>add path</kbd> `screen://`

`5`. If <kbd>Studio Mode</kbd> active, click <kbd>Transition</kbd> in the center of the screen, you have to see your screen in the right window now.

`6`. if desired change the output folder: At the "Controls" panel (right-side), click "Settings", then click "Output" in the left menu.

`7`. Finally, click <kbd>Start Recording</kbd> in "Controls" panel.

Comment: With Debian derivative OBS didn't need any PPA but it was part of the distribution packages. And it recorded both my mic and the desktop/computer at the same time by default, just as I needed

Answer (score 4):

[vokoscreen-ng](https://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html) works for me and it meets your requirements:

- record my screen
- record internal audio
  As well as:
- record you from web-camera
- record your mic

It works for Windows and Linux systems as well.

For Ubuntu you may install it with Ubuntu Software or with command:

```
sudo apt install vokoscreen-ng
```

Comment: This says "audio recording not implemente" when you try to record from mic

Answer (score 2):

I am using [recordscreen.py](https://github.com/cessen/recordscreen) Python script. It launches `ffmpeg` or `avconv` behind the scenes, so make sure you have them installed.

Record entire desktop to `output.mkv` at 15 FPS:

```
recordscreen.py output.mkv
```

Record at 30 FPS with different audio and video codec:

```
recordscreen.py -r 30 --vcodec=vp8 --acodec=pcm output.mkv
```

Or record into `.webm`:

```
recordscreen.py output.webm
```

I haven't tried recording games with it, so I will be interested to hear how it goes.

And just for historical perspective [here's one of the earliest blog posts about it](http://www.davidrevoy.com/article65/recordscreen-py-video-and-audio-capture-from-terminal-for-ubuntu-12-04).

Comment: There are gazillions of screen recorders out there. The gotcha in the question is the recording of the internal audio. How can I record the internal audio, a.k.a. for example if I play a video on a website, the audio stream of that

Comment: @CsabaToth some freshman is needed to research that use case. `ffpmeg` docs are referencing to ALSA for that. http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA#Recordaudiofromanapplicationwhilealsoroutingtheaudiotoanoutputdevice but in `recordscreen.py` `DEFAULT_CAPTURE_AUDIO_DEVICE = "pulse"`.

Comment: Im getting `Unknown encoder libvo_aacenc` error trying this approach