# How to record desktop screen with audio?

Tags: audio-recording, desktop-recording

I have seen this question: [How to Record Screen and internal Audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237027/how-to-record-screen-and-internal-audio)

The answers given here is to install `recordmydesktop`. I have installed it but it does not work. It gives a error message just after selecting the screen area.

Also I have many screen recorder applications but none works perfectly. Some records the screen but not the audio. eg EasyScreenCast. I would like to know how to record screen with audio.

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions in the other answers of the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RecordMyDesktop does not work properly for you, you can use a script instead.

The script can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/amit-upadhyay-IT/RecordScreen/blob/master/shell_file.sh).

To use, copy the script into a text file (use your favourite text editor) and save it in your home directory. Give the script execute permission

```
chmod 755 name-of-your-file
```

Then you can execute it easily:

```
./name-of-your-file
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=screencast-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
FPS=4
THREADS=3

echo "Click the window to capture and get ready!"

tmpfile=/tmp/screengrab.tmp.$$
trap 'touch $tmpfile; rm -f $tmpfile' 0

xwininfo > $tmpfile 2>/dev/null
left=$(grep 'Absolute upper-left X:' $tmpfile | awk '{print $4}');
top=$(grep 'Absolute upper-left Y:' $tmpfile | awk '{print $4}');
width=$(grep 'Width:' $tmpfile | awk '{print $2}');
height=$(grep 'Height:' $tmpfile | awk '{print $2}');
geom="-geometry ${width}x${height}+${left}+${top}"
echo "Geometry: ${geom}"
size="${width}x${height}"
pos="${left},${top}"
echo "pos=$pos size=$size"

sleep 2
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -f x11grab -r $FPS -s $size -i ${DISPLAY-0:0}+${pos} -acodec pcm_s16le $NAME-temp.wav -an -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -threads 0 $NAME-temp.mp4

echo Merge audio+video and encode to webm for YouTube? && read

ffmpeg -i $NAME-temp.mp4 -i $NAME-temp.wav -acodec libvorbis -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libvpx -qscale 8 -me_method full -mbd rd -flags +gmc+qpel+mv4 -trellis 1 -threads $THREADS $NAME.webm
```

Usage is also demonstrated in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKyxeueYZuc).

<sub>Editor's note: please do not give security-risk 777 permissions to the file as shown in the video. 755 will be more than sufficient.</sub>