# Start new GNOME screenshot/screencast tool from CLI in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 22.04, screenshot, desktop-recording

I like the new screenshot tool in GNOME 42/ Ubuntu 22.04.

Although it does miss the possibility to record a window, and an option to record audio.

How do I start recording or take a screenshot from CLI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the terminal command to take a screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot)

Comment: Not sure, the tool changed, that question is about an older tool, and those answers do not work.

Comment: @Janghou your title says "start the tool" and in your question "start recording or take a screenshot". Would you like to open the tool or take action of either start recording or screenshot?

Comment: cli command to start the tool and record a screencast or screenshot

Comment: @Janghou bringing up the tool is possible with a command line though some tweaking is required but after that you need to click the buttons as you wish. If you want to bring up the tool and then still want to use command line, IMHO it is not possible.

Comment: @UnKNOWn And how do you bring up the tool with command line?

Comment: That has already been answered [in this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/194470/307670) I just tried it on 22.04.1 in terminal and it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to record desktop screen with audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739479/how-to-record-desktop-screen-with-audio)

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late answer

apparently gnome has gone crazy and decided to break every screenshot tool by restricting their dbus APIs, and allowing screenshots by their useless tool with keybind only

do alt-f2, type `lg`, then type `global.context.unsafe_mode = true`
after doing that, running this command will launch the interactive screenshot tool

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.screenshotUI.open();'
```

note that enabling unsafe_mode is.. probably unsafe