# How to use speakers as sound input device?

Tags: 16.04, sound

I'd like to use my speakers as the input device, so e.g I could call someone, and they would hear the sound being played on the speaker. Or, to record a video in which the audio is whatever is being played on the speaker. Is that possible on Ubuntu?

Currently, in sound settings, the only input device I see is the internal microphone. I'd like to be able to select the speakers as the input device.

Edit: The linked question doesn't answer my issue - running `pactl load-module module-loopback` just caused a very large amount of beeping to come from my speakers. I also installed Pulseaudio volume control but I still don''t see the option to use speakers as the input device in the input tab.

Comment: For your 2nd example https://askubuntu.com/questions/237027/how-to-record-screen-and-internal-audio this could be the answer.