# How do you install Obs studio on 21.04 "Hirsute Hippo"?

Tags: obs-studio

I downloaded Ubuntu 21.04 "Hirsute Hippo" but I hit a does not have a Release file issue:

[image]

I [couldn't work out how to raise an issue](https://s.natalian.org/2021-05-13/ubuntu.mp4) on the [ppa site](https://launchpad.net/%7Eobsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio).

Comment: You don't need a ppa to install obs-studio, it's in the universe repository.

Comment: What is the CLI commands to install please?

Comment: Remove the unneccessary ppa, make sure universe is enabled (`sudo add-appt-repository universe`) and install with `sudo at install obs-studio`.

Comment: The ppa is for these Ubuntu versions only http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/dists/ .... No **Hirsute**.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/237027/how-to-record-screen-and-internal-audio/974669#974669

Answer (score 0):

Installed from snap

```
sudo snap install obs-studio
```

reference : https://snapcraft.io/install/obs-studio/ubuntu