# Measure FPS of the game

Tags: wine, games, performance

I'd like to find an analogue of [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) or any other fps counter on Ubuntu 12.10.

After some googling I found 2 solutions:

1. To use [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) (I found it from [this discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896317)). This solution didn't work for me because after launching the game:

   ```
   mumble-overlay game
   ```

   I got this error:

   ```
   game: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/mumble/libmumble.so.1: undefined symbol: glPopClientAttrib
   ```

   And I didn't find any fix of this error in the WEB.
2. To use `WINEDEBUG=fps` with `osd_cat`. It works only with [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) (only Windows games). Found from reading [this discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1847105) and [this article](http://www.emmolution.org/?p=188). It shows FPS during play but the output is definitely wrong - 0.15-0.18 fps. And it doesn't matter if game really runs slow or fast - the result is always the same.

Does anyone know how to fix these errors? Or are there any other solutions? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably need something like `glc`, as I discuss [in this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100053/fraps-like-programs-for-ubuntu/192976#192976).

Comment: @Mik yes, I mentioned that in the first sentence.

Comment: The question I linked to wasn't about fraps, it was about alternatives to fraps, i.e. `glc`, as I mentioned in my answer on that question.

Comment: @Mik Actually I need _fps counter_ and it seems that `glc` doesn't have such feature.

Comment: I'm way too lazy to go and test this myself, but I am almost certain that KDE has a plugin for measuring FPS. If you want to install KDE without breaking things you can run apt-get install --install-recommends=false --install-suggests=false kubuntu-desktop. Installing multiple desktop environments though could be risky and again I'm not certain so you should research before you try.

Comment: My guess is that your .xx FPS is related to architecture problems and become a bug report

Comment: .xx fps may be the actual fps divided by 100

Comment: see [Fraps like programs for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/100053/19466)

Comment: You could always go oldschool and write a program that check if a set of pixels has changed, writes the time in micros to a file, and then later check the file for differences in time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BuGLE:

```
$ BUGLE_CHAIN=showfps LD_PRELOAD=/home/sa/Temp/bugle/lib/libbugle.so glxgears

$ cat bugle.log 
[INFO] logstats.frames per second: 36.2 fps
[INFO] logstats.frames per second: 60.1 fps
[INFO] logstats.frames per second: 60.0 fps
[INFO] logstats.frames per second: 59.9 fps
[...]

$ awk '{ s += $5 } END { print "average framerate: ", s/NR }' bugle.log
average framerate:  59.7136
```

You will need to compile and configure BuGLE but this will work with any software using OpenGL to render graphics.

[BuGLE HomePage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/)

Frapix is a software that can make something similar (promises to be similar to Fraps), but keep in mind that BuGLE is the "default" solution to this.

[Frapix Google Project Home](https://code.google.com/p/frapix/)