# Frame rate counter

Tags: wine, 13.04, framerate

Does any one knows if there is an application like frame fraps for ubuntu??

I found this commend and it almost worked

```
WINEDEBUG=fps wine YOURGAME.exe 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr | grep  --line-buffered "^trace:fps:" | cut -c25-30 | osd_cat --lines=1  --font="lucidasanstypewriter-bold-18" --color=yellow
```

[link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1847105&p=11269919#post11269919)

but the problem with it was that it did not show on screen counter and I could not find the output file yes in terminal I could find fps counter throe bunch of errors but I would like to know if there is a better way and if there is not then how to get an output file with commend if any one knows

thank you in advanced

Comment: did you check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/100053/fraps-like-programs-for-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you for the reply but thous are software that record screen and I want a software that measures fps

Comment: I'ts not about the answers, it's about the fact the question is the  same.. You're not asking a different question, so this would kinda be a 'duplicate'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works, but try http://code.fluffytapeworm.com/projects/libglfps

Comment: Most probably that will work :( but I do not know how to compile the software

Comment: Most likely there is a text document named "INSTALL" in the de-compressed file, read that and it will probably tell you what to do.