# Best option for recording Minecraft Server play?

Tags: sound, skype, empathy, minecraft

I am planning on doing some server minecraft screen recording just for fun, and so I've been looking around at what there is to offer. I know FRAPS won't work on Ubuntu and I'd rather not spend the $30 for it anyways, so I looked around and found [glc](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/glc.html), which I thought looked good.

I then googled some more and found this question: [Fraps like programs for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100053/fraps-like-programs-for-ubuntu) and there are two answers, one suggesting glc (which I knew about), and another suggesting gtk-recordmydesktop (also knew about) and VLC streaming (did not know about).

My question is, which of these would have the least impact on RAM and still record my video at good (minimum 360p) quality and get sound from voice chat through an SIP client on my system ([SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol)=Session Initiation Protocol - I would be using Jitsi or Empathy) connected to my friend(s) using Skype.

Answer (score 0):

recordMyDektop is going to be your best option. I've used it in the past, and it's done well for gameplay. As for getting it to receive audio input from Skype or Empathy, that will take a little bit of tweaking with a virtual soundboard. This is explained on recordMyDektop's website [here](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/p1_2c.php).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This records very good video regarding the state of my PC (Core Duo, 2.5GB RAM, yeah.) but it didn't grab any of the sound from Minecraft! Is there something I have to do?

Comment: As mentioned, that will take a little bit of tweaking with a virtual soundboard, assuming your sound card supports recording audio output (for example, mine doesn't). I have a link in the original answer to an article on recordMyDesktop's website explaining how to set up the virtual soundboard.